# SQL Server force multi-threading

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to force a block of T-SQL code to run multi-threaded?

If not, is it possible to avoid running a code block if it would run single-threaded?

Comment: An unusual requirement - you'd rather have no answer than let SQL Server work it out in the way that it sees fit?

Comment: Basically, I have many processes that can run in parallel. Some of these processes get forced to run single threaded based on what else is currently running. The other processes may finish quickly, but the single threaded process continues to run for a very long time. I'm wondering if it would be better if the lengthy process were to do some sort of polling and avoid running until it can run multi-threaded.

Comment: In that case, it may be better to look at some means of breaking up the long running task, or looking at recompile options, so that each "part" of the task can be optimized individually, based on the current load on the server at that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The maximum degree of parallelism can be specified but not the minimum. If a query has a parallel plan the decision about the number of processors to use will be made at each execution time dependant upon current server load.

You could maybe increase the probability of this happening in SQL Server 2008 by using resource govenor and putting the query in a high priority group.

Answer (score 1):

As of [sql-server-2008-r2](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008-r2) and later it is possible to force multi-threading execution.

the following code will force multi-threaded:

```
OPTION ( RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8649 )
```

and this will force single threading

```
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

You can read more on [Paul White's blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20180404164406/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx) or just Google the "QUERYTRACEON 8649"